# deploying React app via CloudFront / S3 vs Docker / EKS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-eks

My app has a frontend built in React and a backend written in Node/Express.

The backend will be containerized and hosted on AWS EKS.

For the frontend Reactjs app, what is the difference between using CloudFront + S3 vs Docker + EKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to evaluate is the **type of React application** you've built:

1. Is it plain React which executes in the browser?
2. Is it React running in a "modern" framework like Nextjs or Remix.run?

Now let's review the **deployment options**

CloudFront:  is a CDN, which is a very fast way to send static files to the clients. By static files we understand: js files, css files, html, etc.
Normally a CDN is deployed in multiple locations, so the clients will get the **static content** from a location close to them.

Docker on the other hand, is a way to execute your application, like your NodeJs backend. Even though it can also serve static files, it's not optimized for delivering **static content**, you will have to take care of that.

**Decisions points**

If your React application has been built with option 1 (executes in browser), the best option is to go with a CDN (cloudfront). You can still deploy it to docker if it's easier for you, but you may reach a point where cost and latency will make a CDN more attractive, but it depends on your use case. For example: if your server and users will be in the same location, you may get away with docker.

For the second option (running nextjs, or other modern react frameworks), you'll have to two options:

1. Deploy it as static content: you can use cloudfront for deployment, and also docker with the penalties discussed for static content.
2. Deploy it as a web server: docker would be a good candidate for deployment, as you cannot deploy the web-server in a CDN. You can do some configuration to place a CDN in front of your web-server, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

Hope it helps

Comment: a React App is a Single Page Application. Is it possible to configure the CloudFront to always serve the `index.html` regardless of what URL path the client requested?

Comment: Yes, definitely. And the react SPA should be able to pick up the path from the url, and run the router (if you are using one).

Comment: If the cloudFront is configured to always serve `index.html` regardless of the URL path, then it would be impossible for the client to request for the necessary css, js, etc files?

Comment: One thing is to say return always index.html, another thing is properly configuring the rules. I recommend reading AWS docs. They even have the whole AWS cloudformation example here for this particular case:
https://github.com/aws-samples/react-cors-spa/blob/main/react-cors-spa-stack.yaml
If that doesn't work (which I doubt it), open an issue there